# Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. I have already allowed access from anywhere but the issue isn't resolved

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, server, database-connection, whitelist

**I keep getting this error although I have allowed access from anywhere in the Network access section of the cluster. (Screenshot of the same is attached below)**

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/runner/store-cipher-backend-1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824:32)
    at /home/runner/store-cipher-backend-1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:380:10
    at /home/runner/store-cipher-backend-1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/home/runner/store-cipher-backend-1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/home/runner/store-cipher-backend-1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1225:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/runner/store-cipher-backend-1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:379:20)
    at intialDbConnection (/home/runner/store-cipher-backend-1/db/db.connect.js:5:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/store-cipher-backend-1/index.js:15:1) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'cluster0-shard-00-00.fkvic.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-01.fkvic.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-02.fkvic.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-on2j4f-shard-0',
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

Here is the connection code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mySecret = process.env['mongoUrl']
const intialDbConnection = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(mySecret, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    console.log("db connected")
    
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

module.exports = { intialDbConnection }
```

**And the entire code is here https://replit.com/@KumaraswamyA/store-cipher-backend-1**

[Access from anywhere mongodb access management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV5rC.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an answer follow this thread. [mongoDB community support](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongooseserverselectionerror-could-not-connect-to-any-servers-in-your-mongodb-atlas-cluster-one-common-reason-is-that-youre-trying-to-access-the-database-from-an-ip-that-isnt-whitelisted/201786)

The MongoDB community has made it clear that the error is not from their end.

and after reaching out to Replit. They responded that they are aware of the issue and have provided a temporary solution:

**“You can run “kill 1” in the shell of your Repl which will reboot it and may fix the issue, although it isn’t a 100% reliable workaround.”**

Apart from this the solution that has worked for **me is changing the file name and running, the DB gets connected. In case you have already used the APIs in the frontend, after doing the above step change back your file name to the old one and the DB gets connected without any issues.**

Cheers.